# How to break lines in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I have two questions, looking for some plugins or something that can:

1. Break lines automatically as you type?
2. Break lines afterwards?

Say, I always want it to be broken at 80. Either justified or aligned to the left is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get automatic wrapping set the [textwidth](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27textwidth%27) option.

To wrap a bunch of text you can use the gq command.

Comment: textwidth is what you're looking for.